# Rails 3.2.6 RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I've been beating my head against the wall for a little too long. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but here goes. I added the following line to my routes.rb file:

```
get '/:location_or_budget.:format' => 'listings#search_by_location_or_budget', as: :search
```

When I run 'rake routes', I see this route in the output:

```
search GET    /:location_or_budget.:format     listings#search_by_location_or_budget
```

When I try to use the route in my code like this:

```
link_to name, search_path(:location_or_budget => 'boston')
```

I get the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"listings", :action=>"search_by_location_or_budget", :location_or_budget=>"boston"}):
```

I feel like I set everything up correctly. I've verified that the method 'search_by_location_or_budget' exists and is public. Does anyone know what might be wrong or how I might go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you requirest :format part. Try this:

```
get '/:location_or_budget.:format' => 'listings#search_by_location_or_budget', :as => :search, :defaults => { :format => 'html' }
```

Or

```
get '/:location_or_budget(.:format)' => 'listings#search_by_location_or_budget', :as => :search
```

Comment: You nailed it. That was exactly what the problem was.